# Is java.util.List mutable?

Tags: java

We are able to `add`/`remove` elements to `List` using `add()`/`remove()` methods without creating another list which looks similar to `StringBuilder` `append`. Because of this I think `List` is mutable.

Can anyone confirm my understanding is correct?

If it is wrong please explain the code below:

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("abc");
strList.add("xyz");
```

Comment: Yes it is mutable as you can change its internal state

Comment: `List` is mutable AFAIK, but Guava has some immutable collections.

Comment: ArrayList is mutable. Not all implementations of `List` are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`java.util.List` is an interface. Implementation could be mutable or immutable depending on which you use. If you're wondering about `java.util.ArrayList` - it is mutable and it is not creating another `List` instance on `add()` or `remove()`.

If you are looking for immutable list - check `Guava` implementation of [ImmutableList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) or [Collections.unmodifiableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) which throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` on modifications.

Answer (score 30):

## List mutability

Since `List` is an interface, the only promise it makes is: "these are the methods you will get".

The `List` interface describes a *mutable* List. Notice that it has functions such as `add()`, `set()` and `remove()`. But notice also that these mutators are [designated as "optional" operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

There exist implementations of the `List` interface which are, in practice, immutable.

```
List<Integer> mutable = new ArrayList<>();
mutable.add(1);

List<Integer> immutable = Collections.unmodifiableList(mutable);
// try to modify the list
immutable.add(2);
// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

`Collections.unmodifiableList()` returns an instance of the `List` implementation `Collections.UnmodifiableList`.

`Collections.UnmodifiableList` forwards all calls of *immutable* `List` functions, correctly to the underlying `List`. Whereas it implements all *mutable* `List` functions by throwing `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

## List element mutability

If we do:

```
List<Date> mutable = new ArrayList<>();
mutable.add(new Date());
List<Date> immutable = Collections.unmodifiableList(mutable);
Date myCoolDate = immutable.get(0);
```

Can we mutate `myCoolDate`? Absolutely.

```
myCoolDate.setTime(99999); // works! mutates the original Date object in the `List`.
```

The `List` — whether immutable or otherwise — stores *copies of references to objects*. Once we have a reference to the object (`Date myCoolDate = immutable.get(0);`), we can mutate the object freely.

The items in an immutable list have *no immutability guarantee*. They are *exactly as mutable as they have always been*.

Comment: Also note that in the first example you can still add elements like `mutable.add(3);` after creating the `immutable` variable, and those will show up in the `immutable` list as well. So even the `immutable` list can change, just not through the methods of the `immutable` variable.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It's mutable. 
If you want to have an immutable one, you can wrap it using java utility Collections class:
java.util.Collections#unmodifiableList

like this:

```
  List<Object> mutableList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Object> immutableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(mutableList);
```

Comment: I find this answer confusing on the border of misleading. The question, as I understood it, was whether `List` is mutable. You show an example where it is and one where it it not. The examples are correct, so I certainly would not say “Yes. It's mutable”.

Comment: Misleading it is. List is neither mutable not immutable, it is an interface whose behaviour is implementation-specific, as clearly detailed in @Birchlabs' answer.