# Does Map store copy of the reference variable or copy of the object?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, immutability, pass-by-value

I have this small code snippet and want to know whether the implementations of `java.Util.Map` store of copy of reference variable or the copy of the object.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> obj = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> a = new HashMap<>();
    a.put(0, obj);
    a.get(0).forEach(System.out::print);
    obj = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
    System.out.println();
    a.get(0).forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

Output

```
123
123
```

I had a feeling that the answer to this must exist already (Ok, it may already exist but I couldn't find it), I read the following answers but couldn't get much about my problem

[Does Java return by reference or by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297937/does-java-return-by-reference-or-by-value)

This answer says that it could have happened if `Integer` was mutable, but `ArrayList` is mutable ([Is java.util.List mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438544/is-java-util-list-mutable)) so why isn't it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there might be a little misunderstanding here. When you do initially `List<Integer> obj = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);`, the objected referenced by `obj` is a list containing 1,2,3. This very list is put in the map.

However, when you do `obj = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);`, you are assigning a new object to the reference `obj`.

Try this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<>();
        obj.add(1);
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> a = new HashMap<>();
        a.put(0, obj);
        a.get(0).forEach(System.out::println);
        obj.add(2);
        System.out.println();
        a.get(0).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I feel stupid, I in my mind replaced the object and kept the reference and forgot that map copies a reference to the object, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Don't worry we all been there! I make silly errors all the time, what really helps me is a nice IDE (I use intellij for java and vscode for python/js/ts). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First of: [`Arrays::asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) creates a fixed-sized list.
Second this line

```
obj = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
```

creates **a new list object**.

To test your hypothesis, we need to create a modifiable list, add it to the map, then modify the list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
  Map<Integer, List<Integer>> a = new HashMap<>();
  a.put(0, obj);
  a.get(0).forEach(System.out::print);
  obj.clear();
  obj.add(4);
  obj.add(5);
  obj.add(6);
  System.out.println();
  a.get(0).forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tW2iHg)

We see the following output:

```
123
456
```

which confirms that the map does not copy the list, but only holds a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.